# Magento custom shippment method

Tags: magento, module

I wrote shippment module with checking a lot of resources/tutorials etc. I am using magento 1.9. Source of module is:
https://github.com/aleextra/magentoshipping

I lost full day to find why it doesn't works fine. Magento see my module, when I am adding at Model/Carrier.php at line 52 code:

```
die($result);
```

it shows objec dump:

```
   Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result Object
(
    [_rates:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Method Object
                (
                    [_data:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [carrier] => mikshipping
                            [carrier_title] => Mik Carrier
                            [method] => fixed
                            [method_title] => Fixed price 10
                            [price] => 10
                            [cost] => 10.00
                        )

                    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1
                    [_origData:protected] => 
                    [_idFieldName:protected] => 
                    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
                    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [_error:protected] => 
)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: And additional, magento returns me:
Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.

Comment: can you paste entire code of the carrier model?

Comment: it seems that  your 'die' placed before an wrapping that returned false to magento core.  Is that others validations that could have done this, after this die message?

Answer (score 0):

As a quick guess I say that your carriers name in the config.xml (mshipping) does not match the code used in Carrier.php (mikshipping). I have them always being the same so Iḿ not absolutely sure if this might cause the issue, but it is easy to check.